# Реализация 4-х мерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Есть функция вычисляющая f(int a,b,c,d) неизвестное кол-во раз, различных вариантов будет примерно до 3 млн. Надо эффективно размещать эти результаты для дальнейшего использования без вызова функции. Все от abs(a - b) до abs(с - d) вероятно меньше 4 и в цикле они увеличиваются от 0 до n (т.е. в начале они в среднем >= 0 в конце в среднем <= n). Сделал реализацию на unordered_map
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map:

- Функция find вызывает equal функцию (типа bool) 2 раза, зачем?, здесь нет сортировки...
- Комп - `comp_func = [](const key_t &x, const key_t &y) { return !memcmp(&x, &y, 16); };` - на скорость обычно не влияет, в идеале ее удалить надо.
- Хеш - `hash_func = [](const key_t &x) { return x.a * 400 - x.b * 49 - x.c * 7 - x.d + 171; };` - так думаю лучший вариант, при переполнении новые полезут на самые старые (вроде бы) и их может получится заменять.
- Может стоит написать через другой/свой контейнер?, слишком простые варианты как `std::vector<std::vector<res_t>>` не годны - в 2 раза быстрее, взамен много лишнего г.
- Похоже сильно быстрее не получится, может уже так не плохо? Или как в таких ситуациях правильно делать?

upd: ответить пока-что не могу, допишу здесь - хеш не просто так взят, bucket равен максимальному "числу" хеша, поэтому я его максимально упаковал, оно почти не влияет на скорость, тестировал примерно - 0.24с на 1 млн. рандом доступа. Тут раном-не-рандом все место и так заполнится и пойдут лишние прямые сравнения снижающие скорость. Обычный вектор 0.12с на млн, т.е не похоже что сильно тормозит, пока что так, может я где-то ошибся. Больше всего непонятно когда 1 элемент в куске и хеш одинаковый зачем еще 2 (!) прямых сравнения идут, хоть это и не тормозит сильно

Comment: Хеш не слишком хорош, советую взять что-нибудь порандомнее и сделать без умножения - оно тоже влияет на производительность, если уж придираться :) Заменить можно на побитовые операции.

Comment: Для тебя принципиальна нужно хранить все предыдущие результаты вычислений? Возможно стоит применить вытесняющий кэш, на основе std::vector< std::tuple< size_t, key_t, result_t > > ( первый элемент - хеш ключа, храним значение в ячейке hesh % vector.size() ). За счет отсутствия косвенности и меньшего объему памяти, может быть прирост производительности.

Comment: Ну я к чему-то подобному уже сам додумал, `std::vector<std::pair<key_t,res_t>>`. Доступ - в ячейку hash и проверка key на равенство, для этого все key должны инициированы неправильно в начале... так?, или с tuple не так (не знаком с этим, и многим другим..). Хотелось бы без придумывания функции хеша что-нибудь, чтобы оно само заполняло буфер целиком. Пока что map мне больше нравится - помнит все варианты и меньше кода писать:)

Comment: при инициализации std::vector< std::pair<key_t,res_t> > holder( size, std::make_pair< key_t(0,0,0,0),  fn( key_t( 0,0,0,0 ) ); мы инициализируем все значения вектора одним значением ключа. В случае с tuple - тоже самое. Дополнительное место для хранения хэша нужно по двум причинам: (1) вероятность несовпадения хэша (при несовпадении ключей) выше чем несовпадение первого элемента ключа. Сокращается вермя на ненужные проверки. (2) ненужно пересчитывать хэшы, если мы решим сделать resize вектору.